# How to determine if a control handle is of a native (or based on native one) win32 ListBox?

Tags: c#, winapi, listbox

The problem can be expressed in a simple way like this: Given a control handle (IntPtr), how do we know if it is of a `ListBox` or in general it would be better if we know what kind of control it is.

I suppose that the ListBox creator does not put any info (such as the plain text "ListBox") inside the class name of the ListBox (the class name can be obtained using `GetClassName` function.

I need to do this because I need to determine if there is any native win32 ListBox under a certain screen point. The first step is to find the control handle using `WindowFromPoint` function, but next we need to check if the found handle is of a ListBox or not.

### Update

When I say ***native listbox*** I mean the control can be created using `CreateWindow` and then the `class name` can be specified with any string. I suppose that class name does not contain any fixed phrase like `LISTBOX`, as for the ListBox in WindowsForms, the class name of it has a format like **WindowsForms10.LISTBOX.app.0.bf771...**

Comment: `GetClassName` -> string comparison.

Comment: @JonathanPotter the class name can be any (it's put in by the control creator). So I suppose there is not any info in that to know if it's a ListBox.

Comment: That makes no sense. If it's a native listbox control, the class name will be `"LISTBOX"`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter OK, maybe I misunderstood about native control, but what I mean here is some custom one based on that native. I've tried spying some ListBoxes (which are actually native or maybe of some WindowsForms) and the class names are very different.

Comment: @JonathanPotter please see my update to understand what I mean. People always want to use the class name `LISTBOX` but that's not the must-do. And for the case of WindowsForms, you can see the class name is very different. In other cases they can use a totally arbitrary class name like `mylb`

Comment: Why do you need to know if the list under the cursor is windowed instead of windowless? Are you trying to automate it? If so, consider using UI Automation instead.

Comment: Oh boy, you've got this all backwards. It's not the call to `CreateWindow` that defines a window class. `RegisterClass` does. And the class name for **any** standard listbox is `LISTBOX`. If you find a window with another class name, you aren't dealing with a standard listbox. Only a standard listbox knows how to handle `LB_XXX` messages. Throwing these messages at anything else will horribly break things.

Comment: @IInspectable you are completely not expert at Win32, the ListBox in WindowsForms has class name of **WindowsForms10.LISTBOX.app.0.bf771...** - and it's not exactly **LISTBOX** but it responds to the LB_xxxx OK, it's just a custom win32 ListBox with a **custom class name**.

Comment: *"it's just a custom win32 ListBox with a custom class name"* - In other words: It's **not** a standard Win32 listbox. Whether it responds to some, or all of the `LB_XXX` messages, and how it does, is an implementation detail, and completely undocumented. If you feel like subscribing to this type of hackery, be my guest. Just don't post it as an answer on a Q&A site that's visited by professionals.

Comment: @IInspectable you just know about Win32, but not know about Windows Forms, so you're not expert. don't consider yourself as professional. Windows Forms adds layer to help filter messages handled by the underlying Win32 ListBox, it's just based on that native one.

Comment: @andlabs as I understand UIAutomation is what you have been given and not all applications give that to you. It's not a magic. It's just kind of a service provided by the programmer who built the app. If they don't provide, you have nothing. Also my purpose is a little different, I'm just building my own library (some kind of a collection of helper classes) to deal and play with Win32 =)

Comment: Please stop making this personal. If all you have is a window handle then it's a pure win32 question. Using UP automation to find out the type of control is likely the most robust solution. But there is no 100% fool proof solution.. That is demonstrably impossible.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm not so sure but do you mean all Win32 controls can be explored by using UI Automation? The developers built those controls made that possible? (they built the API provider there and we as on the API client side can use UI Automation?) really weird.

Answer (score -3):

Well I have had the idea of sending some special message to the ListBox to test it. I started trying with the message `LB_GETCOUNT`, however it actually cannot help in this case.

So I've tried another message `LB_GETTEXTLEN` in which I passed in an invalid item index (such as `-1`) and see if the returned result is totally different and distinct to help recognize a ListBox from other controls. And yes it can help, for the ListBox the returned value is `-1` while for other controls the returned value is just `0`.

Here is the code:

```
//LB is a defined enum for ListBox messages, which can be found in pinvoke
var isListBox = User32.SendMessage(handle, (uint)LB.LB_GETTEXTLEN, -1, 0).ToInt32() != 0;
```

Comment: Lord, no! Like all other controls, the listbox declares it's class-specific messages in the `WM_USER+x` range. Throwing a `LB_GETTEXTLEN` at arbitrary controls may be interpreted as a `CM_KILLARMYOFKITTENS` messages. What a horrible, horrible idea. Jonathan Potter gave you the correct answer in comments. Don't just ignore it.

Comment: @IInspectable and yes you live in the world of Win32 but completely don't understand the world of Win32 wrapper named ***Windows Forms*** - just 8 questions/answered tagged with `winforms` - In another speaking, you don't even know that the class name can be customized to make it totally different?

Comment: @IInspectable I don't argue against you about the bad idea of my solution ***BUT*** I'm arguing against you about suggesting me to use the solution of Jonathan Potter (who gave you an upvote on your comment). That solution completely does not work generally (and not always work because there is not any binding to the class name).

Comment: Clearly you can't throw arbitrary messages at arbitrary windows. Stop doing that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan do you mean that is some kind of bad app? And I can build some app of my own to destroy other apps (like a virus or malware) by simply doing so? If so the Win32 Messages System is so terrible.

Comment: Read the first comment to this answer again.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan instead of saying no, if you have any better idea, please share. I agree that it is some kind of hack, but I don't have any other choice to achieve just a simple requirement - know if the control can understand LB_***** messages (or in other words, some kind of a win32 listbox )?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan so please read my comment after that. What if I create a ListBox having a class name which does not contain any phrase `LISTBOX`? how to know if it is a list box then?

Comment: *"What if I create a ListBox having a class name which does not contain any phrase LISTBOX? how to know if it is a list box then?"* - In that case the answer is simple: You haven't created a listbox then. And now, do yourself a favor and read the documentation for [RegisterClassEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633587.aspx).

Comment: If you don't know any more about the class than its name them you categorically cannot send it class private messages. With all respect, this is the point where it pays to be experienced in Win32.

Comment: @IInspectable I just have basic understanding about Win32, never worked with them directly using C++, just via pInvoke using C#.  So bear with me, but just a simple question *Can I (or any other) create a ListBox with some registered class name like "MYLB"*? If so how can I know if the control handle is of a ListBox (not a native, maybe it's just based on that one)? As suggested using UI Automation may be the right solution (but I've still not had any idea about how to use it yet).